# Laravel trying to get topics that have no posts

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables, topics and posts. I want to get only the topics that have no posts.

I tried to use order by, but then I have topics that have no posts and also some that have posts, so it's wrong.

```php
Topic::where('locale', $locale)
    ->withCount('posts')
    ->orderBy('posts_count', 'ASC')
    ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: What are you trying to get? All topics that don't have any posts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to get all topics that do not have posts, try this:

```
Topic::doesntHave('posts')->paginate(15);
```

If you want to filter for a certain (maximum) count of posts, do this:

```
Topic::has('posts', '<=', $count)->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the topics without any posts, you can use `doesntHave` if your models are setup properly:

```
$topicsWithoutPosts= Topic::doesntHave('posts')->where('locale',$locale)->paginate(15);
```